# Why does the result of IsGenericType differ in these examples?

Tags: c#, generics

I have functions, which generate collection of char objects:

```
public static IEnumerable<char> generic_foo<T>()
{
    return "1231";
}
public static IEnumerable<char> generic_foo2<T>()
{
    yield return '1';
    yield return '2';
    yield return '3';
}
public static IEnumerable<char> foo()
{
    return "1231";
}
public static IEnumerable<char> foo2()
{
    yield return '1';
    yield return '2';
    yield return '3';
}

public static void Main()
{
    var res = foo().GetType().IsGenericType;  //  False
    var gen_res = generic_foo<int>().GetType().IsGenericType;  //  False

    var res2 = foo2().GetType().IsGenericType;  //  False
    var gen_res2 = generic_foo2<int>().GetType().IsGenericType;  //  True
}
```

I was wondered by results of program. Why are result different?
What is the key difference between foo2/generic_foo2 methods?

Comment: As an aside, it's a good idea to use idiomatic method names even in small sample code - anything that distracts from the reader is a bad idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`generic_foo2()` is implemented by the compiler via a state machine. That state machine will be generic in `T` even though you're not actually using it - so calling `GetType()` on the instance of the state machine will give a generic type. It wouldn't be worth the compiler noting that you're never actually using `T` and creating a non-generic state machine... this is a rare corner case. (Why would you make a method generic and not use the type parameter anywhere?)

The state machine created for `foo2()` doesn't need to be generic because the method itself is not generic.

`generic_foo()` and `foo` are just returning strings though, and `System.String` is definitely not a generic type.

Answer (score 3):

You are making the mistake looking too much to the return types of the method. The inner working of `generic_foo2` is a whole lot different than that of `generic_foo` and they both return different types.

For the `generic_foo2` method, the compiler generates a state-machine (using `Enumerator<T>` and which iterates over the results). `Enumerator<T>` *is* a generic type.

Your `generic_foo` method just returns a string, a static type which happens to implement a generic interface. And a `string` is not a generic type, at least not when I checked :) .

Answer (score 1):

The methods are returning different types, types that implement IEnumerable but aren't actually generic;

Let's delineate what each function is actually returning.

```
generic_foo<T>() => returns string;
foo() => returns string;
generic_foo2<T>() => returns Enumerable of chars;
foo2() => returns Enumerable of chars;
```

For the methods that return strings, it's easy to see why IsGenericType is false, string is not a generic type.

Regarding why the methods that return the enumerable of chars differ is due to the state machines created by the yield statement.  Since foo2 is not a generic method, the state machine created is not generic whereas the state machine for generic_foo2 is generic since the method is generic.